# Is there a plugin or tool I can install that allows browser's to read Typescript raw?

Tags: typescript

Just out of curiosity, I was wondering if there were any experimental tools out there being developed or already exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Just out of curiosity, I was wondering if there were any experimental tools out there being developed or already exists.

Checkout `script` tag support for TypeScript https://github.com/basarat/typescript-script

```
<script type="text/typescript" src="script.ts"></script>
<script type="text/typescript">
    setTimeout(()=>console.log('hello'));
</script>
```